# C# Serializer.serialize does not write to specified file

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a method called `FillFile()` which is supposed to write to specific json file.
The method itself looks like as follows ( I referred to [this documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeWithJsonSerializerToFile.htm) from newtonsoft):

```
  private void FillFile()
        {
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(path))
                {
                    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    serializer.Serialize(file, transactions);
                }
            }
        }
```

transactions comes in type of `List<Transaction>`

```
public static string path = @"Reader\transactions.json";
```

At the end the program does not show any error, but does not write to my file `transactions.json` file
From the debugging I can see my list in also not empty
[image]

Comment: Inspect the properties of the StreamWriter's wrapped FileStream in the debugger and look for the full file path. Likely you are looking in the wrong place since you're using a relative path. The file would be in the bin/debug/framework/reader folder or similar

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 got it thank you very much . That worked for me. But how i can use my file? not the one which is in debug

Comment: Use the full path... Or use the original since It's likely set to "copy to output" folder